Getting the inner HTML value from the dropdown
I am using a Bootstrap dropdown like this:
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue('myvalue')">My Value</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue('someothervalue')">Some Other Label</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

and the function looks like this:
getMyValue(todo: string) {
  console.log("selected value is:", todo);
  console.log("selected text is:", ???);
}

Instead of parsing the text as the second parameter like "My Value 01", "02" etc.
Is there any way I can omit this and use it smart so I don't need to write the same things several times?

You can pass the event to your method.
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue('myval1', $event)"
    >My Value 01</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue('myval2', $event)"
    >My Value 02</a>
</li>

And retrieve the label with event.target.value.
getMyValue(todo: string, event: any) {
  console.log('selected value is:', todo);
  console.log("selected text is:", event.target.text);
}


Alternatively, you may consider working with an array to generate the HTML elements.
So you can pass each item element to the method during click event.
items = [
  { value: 'myval1', label: 'My Value 01' },
  { value: 'myval2', label: 'My Value 02' },
];

getMyValue(item: any) {
  console.log('selected value is:', item.value);
  console.log('selected text is:', item.label);
}

<li *ngFor="let item of items">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue(item)"
  >{{item.label}}</a>
</li>

Demo @ StackBlitz

You can use @for for running the loop and using @if with as syntax, to create the display label and reuse it for both the function and the label!
Angular Control Flow Syntax
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @for(i of arr;track $index) {
      <li>
        @if(i?.toString()?.padStart(2);as displayName) {
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="getMyValue('myval' + i, displayName)">My Value {{displayName}}</a>
        }
      </li>
      }
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  getMyValue(todo: string, displayName: string) {
    console.log('selected value is:', todo);
    console.log('selected text is:', displayName);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
